# Two await calls into one statement

Tags: c#, linq

I've searched but didn't find something that would clear my thoughts on this question..
Is this piece of code a bad practice? Or is it okay to have two await calls such as this?
I'm not sure if this 2 awaits could somehow run into some kind of issue..

```
var numero = await _context.xpto
            .AnyAsync(s => s.field1 == value1) ? await _context.xpto
            .Where(a => a.field1 == value1)
            .MaxAsync(a => a.field2) : 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with two `await` keywords in the same statement.

However, this code could probably be simplified by using [`DefaultIfEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx) as follows:

```
var numero = await _context.xpto
    .Where(a => a.field1 == value1)
    .Select(a => a.field2)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .MaxAsync();
```

Instead of using the ternary operator to handle the case where the query is empty, `DefaultIfEmpty()` catches this case and returns a single default-valued element. This is probably also easier to read and more expressive of the intent. And it requires only a single pass through the sequence (your version makes two passes).

But back to your question, as long as you're conscious of order of evaluation and possible side effects including async exceptions, there's nothing wrong with multiple `await`s.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wasn't familiar with DefaultIfEmpty() but that won't help me. I forgot to mention that in my particular case the type of the object returned, is not initialized, so the default is null and I want an int value which is a not nullable property of the object. I had my question answered, which was about the await calls. It really needs to have that condition in this case, it was the only solution we found to have the method working properly..

Comment: @ButtercupCumbersnatch In that case you can (and should) use the `DefaultIfEmpty()` overload that takes an argument specifying what value to insert; just pass in 0. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419(v=vs.110).aspx Doing this not only saves you an extra pass through the sequence but also eliminates any potential for atomicity issues.

Comment: Thank you! When I tried it yesterday the type returned was of type **xpto** object. The `Select` was the secret here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the code without the conditional operator:

```
var any = await 
    _context.xpto.Any( //...);

int numero;

if (any)
{
    numero = 
       await _context.xpto
                     .Where(//...)
                     .MaxAsync(//...);
}
else
{
     numero = 0;
}
```

Does that look wrong somehow? To me it doesn’t, you are just making an awaitable task a continuation of another awaitable task.

Comment: To respect the flow of the whole application, this is not what I'm after. Bu thank you for the answer :)